How to inspect hash name variables in Typescript when debugging in Chrome
In our Angular project using Nx, we want to switch to hash name syntax for our private fields and methods.
While testing and debugging we noticed that, either in Chrome DevTools or in VSCode attached to Chrome, it is not possible to inspect the private fields.
The console tells me:
Uncaught Error Error: Cannot read private member #bar from an object whose class did not declare it
    at eval (repl:1:9)

I've read, that this should work in Chrome DevTools, eg. on MDN:

Note: Code run in the Chrome console can access private properties outside the class. This is a DevTools-only relaxation of the JavaScript syntax restriction.

In a simplified example (Stackblitz), it is possible to inspect the hash name variables, but our case it still does not work. I can imagine, that the issue might be connected to the TypeScript compilation or the Angular build process.
Is there a way to debug our code and inspect the private fields in VSCode or any browser DevTools?

How are you using that class? Please add a [mre] of it

Have you tried using the debugger in your browser? I can read the value in the debugger. I've also tried the debugger in VSCode attached to Chrome and it works.

Yes, I tried the debugger from the browser, I think the issue might be connected with the build process. The code example in my question is probably misleading, since our project is a quite big Angular project. I will edit my question.
